# what is the best practice to write query strings, JavaScript?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was writing query strings for Cypher import CSV file into Neo4j database. I write 10 lines of query. When I run the query, there are a lot of errors.
I tried to fix it but later realized better to rewrite piece by piece while making sure at each step it works.

What is best practice to write a very long query? I can't linebreak, so should I write a very long line? Is there a way to make life easier in such cases?

I am new to database, so I want to know helpful practices.

Comment: Why you "can't line break"? What reason?

Comment: @stdob-- it seems linebreak is an invalid character. I got such error.

Comment: In what part? Cypher allows the use of any combination of empty space. Including linebreak.  I think that your problem is on the side of the javascript. Or node.js?

Comment: In any case, without an example of a query and an exact indication of the programming language, your question is not answered.

Comment: @stdob-- I thought query strings have similar problems. I will include example soon.

Comment: @stdob-- I am using node.js

Comment: Node.js? Ok, you need try back apostrophe instead common apostrophe or quotes.